# VueJS function with then

Tags: vue.js

I have the following method:

```
    getData(id){
          this.$store.dispatch('getData', {
            employeeId: this.employeeId
          }).then(() => {
            if (this.employeeData.length) {
              // here some code...
            }
          });
        },
 selectEmployee(d) {

      this.getData(d.employeeId);

      // I need to execute this only after getData has been processed...
      this.$store.dispatch('fetchHistory');
    },
```

So what I would like to do is something like this:

```
selectEmployee(d) {

          this.getData(d.employeeId).then(() => {
             // check data here and then execute the fetch
             this.$store.dispatch('fetchHistory');
          });

        },
```

But I get error in the `then` secuence, seems is not allowed there.

> Any clue?

Comment: you aren't returning anything from `getData`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return the promise in `getData`, then you can do `getData().then()`:

```js
getData(id){
  return this.$store.dispatch('getData', {
            employeeId: this.employeeId
         }).then(() => {
           if (this.employeeData.length) {
              // here some code...
           }
         });
}
```

Comment: Amazing!! Thanks alot

Answer (score 2):

Instead of chaining Promises, you could also use ES6s async await, which makes for cleaner more readable code.

```
async getData(id) {
    await this.$store.dispatch('getData', {
        employeeId: id,
    });

    if(this.employeeDate) //do something
},

async selectEmployee(d) {
    await this.getData(d.employeeId);

    // I need to execute this only after getData has been processed...
    this.$store.dispatch('fetchHistory');
},
```